# XSLTProcessor outputting pink error block to be suppressed

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm getting an error block rendered by my xslt and I need to stop it because I simply don't have any control over the content of the XML going into it. I don't care if it can't process successfully, but I do care that is huge error message not be displayed at the top of my output.

The code generating the problem is in this related question:

[Safari not processing HTML from XSL the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695486/safari-not-processing-html-from-xsl-the-same)

But, specifically, it says (in a big pink box):

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 64 at column 332: Opening and ending tag mismatch: IMF
>   line 0 and p
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

The page is fine, I just don't want the error message because, ultimately, there is nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is designed for processing XML. If you give it something that isn't XML, then you can expect it to complain loudly. If you want to process something that isn't XML, don't use XSLT.

Comment: It is processing XML, it's just not entirely complete. The question is, how do I stop it from complaining loudly, or is that simply not an option in this case?

Comment: Well, I got round it by using a little JQuery to simply remove the annoying message. Hey ho.